# Qt 5 parsing HTML on Android

Tags: android, html, c++, qt, dom

I'm developing a cross platform mobile app with Qt 5.3.1. I need to load various HTML pages and parse DOM element values from them. At the moment I have succesfully loaded a page with QNetworkAccessManager and stored it in QByteArray but I hit the wall trying to parse the valuable data out from it.
Couple points:

- I can't use QWebkit since it's not supported on Android on Qt 5
- The HTML can't be assumed being strict mark up, eg Qt's XML readers or DOM parsers won't work on their own
- I'm only parsing text from pages. The information is all i need, not visual style

What options do I have? It sounds a little bit stupid that WebKit would be the only way doing this, since I don't need to display any graphical data from webpages. Is writing my own DOM parser for HTML the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Handling_HTML

Has a pretty good list of html parsers that are available.

Sometimes a good regular expression can catch what you need, but it isn't as robust as a good HTML parser.

The first link on the page looks pretty promising:

http://tidy.sourceforge.net/libintro.html

I don't know how difficult it would be to build the libraries for Qt Android, but it looks do-able, and works with standard tools.

Hope that helps.